# UITableView top offset when used in UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay on iOS 11

Tags: uitableview, ios11

I'm using a UITableView in a split view controller, and it was working fine in iOS 10 and earlier (and also the old iOS10 build running on iOS 11). Now, building for iOS 11 in XCode, the top of the UITableView gets displaced when the keyboard focus is removed and the view is in an iPad portrait UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay:

[image]

[image]

There is a constraint that the bar below the search box has its bottom aligned with the top of the table view. And as far as I can tell, the table view reports the correct top offset both before and after the keyboard is retracted. The console reports no constraint bugs. The bar and table view were added to the split controller view when the Search button was pressed at a time that the keyboard was up (which shows correctly, it's only wrong after the keyboard is lowered).

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an artefact of the new content insets behaviour in iOS 11, and solved by

```
tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
```